# Toggle display shows the hidden element for a second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show a hidden text on click of a button. But when I load the page, the text shows for a second and then disappears. Why would that happen?

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="temp">This is temporary</p>
  <button id="showme">Show</button>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".temp").hide();
  $("#showme").on("click", function() {
    $(".temp").show();
  });
});
```

Comment: SO hide it with CSS to start. That is the best way to handle FOUC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to understand how the webpage loads. Your jquery is executed when the entire page is rendered with the associated CSS. So the browser displays your text for a second till it executes jquery to hide that text. So your browser needs to know that this text is hidden while parsing the html. You can do this by giving a CSS style to the text.

CSS:

```
.temp {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <p class="temp">This is temporary</p>
  <button id="showme">Show</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showme").on("click", function() {
    $(".temp").show();
  });
});
```

Comment: did you copied from somewhere ? so fast

Comment: I obviously copied the code from the question itself. The remaining 4 LINES, I can write in 5 seconds. So what are to trying to prove here? *wondering*

Comment: what 4 lines in 5 sec ? :D

Comment: I think he means 4 lines of explaination. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

You should use inline style tag in `<p>` tag like this:

```
<p class="temp" style="display: none;">This is temporary</p>
```

instead of hiding it from jQuery!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showme").on("click", function() {
    $(".temp").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <p class="temp" style="display: none;">This is temporary</p>
  <button id="showme">Show</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Inline CSS is VERY SERIOUSLY frowned upon. You should avoid it almost all the time.